# How do you find all the elements of a maximal cyclic subgroup of the group of units of a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}_{4}[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$, where $f(x)=x^4+x+1$, there is a maximal cyclic subgroup of $R^{\times}$ (group of units of $R$), that we may denote by $G_{15}$, of order $15=2^{\operatorname{deg} (f(x))}-1$.

I want to know how would you find explicitly all the elements of the cyclic group $G_{15}$?

Comment: It was also mentioned that the element $\alpha$ that is the root of $f(x)$ is such that $\alpha^2$ generates $G_{15}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $R/(2)\cong \mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^4+x+1)$ is the field of order $2^4$, its multiplicative group is cyclic of order $15$. (Maybe this is where you heard the phrase "maximal cyclic?") From this it is clear that $R$ is a local ring with $240$ units (everything except the $2^4$ nilpotent elements.)

Let $b$ be a preimage of a generator of this group. Then $15$ divides the order of $b$, so $\langle b\rangle$ is divisible by $15$. So the problem can be reduced to finding a primitive element of a finite field.

Comment: Hi. When you said let $b$ be a preimage, where exactly is this preimage? Also, I'm not sure but are you saying $\langle b \rangle = G_{15}$? How would you go about finding $b$?

Comment: @Maria I mean the preimage in $R$ via the quotient map I mentioned.  The order of $b$ must be divisible by $15$, but I haven't shown that it's exactly $15$. If what you're saying is true, then it can't have higher order anyway, so whatever you find will be of order $15$. If the thing you pick had order $30$ or more you will have a counterexample to your statement. There are many questions about finding primitive elements in finite fields on this site. When there are just $16$ elements you can manually search.